# Can devices draw power from the MacBook's 3.5 mm audio port?

Tags: macbook-pro

Can devices draw any power from the 3.5 mm audio port on MacBook Pros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this depends on why you're asking the question:

Is the audio port intended to be used for drawing power? - No.

Can a device theoretically draw power from the audio port? - Yes.

Can a device draw enough power to for example charge a phone? - No.

I.e. in most practical circumstances and "wishful thinking" about the audio port - the answer is no. However, if you're doing a hobby project, control the audio output and think it would be fun to power a single LED or similar - that's within reach.

Comment: How much power can a device theoretically draw? and is it possible to draw power from it while listening to music through it?

Comment: @theonlygusti Let me know what you intend to draw power for, and we can go into more specifics. If the intention is to draw power, you usually wouldn't be listening to music at the same time, but rather maximize the power by outputting non-music.

Comment: Just to clarify regarding the amount of power - expect milliwatt range.